# Specific relation between the classical Fourier transform for finite abelian groups and the QFT for finite abelian groups

Tags: mathematics, quantum-fourier-transform

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle#1|}$
I am a math undergrad (with admittedly minimal background in quantum computing) trying to figure out the precise relationship (if any) between the quantum Fourier transform for finite *abelian* groups and the classical Fourier transform for those groups. Here is my attempt so far…

Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian group. We know $G\cong\Z/n_1\Z\times\dots\times\Z/n_r\Z$ For some positive integers $n_1,\dots,n_r$, so I write the irreducible characters of $G$ as
$$
\chi_x(g) = \prod_{j=1}^r\exp(2\pi i x_j g_j/n_j)
$$
where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_r)\in G$ with each $x_i\in \Z/n_i\Z$, and likewise for $g\in G$. I believe this labeling (i.e., the map $x\mapsto\chi_x$) gives an isomorphism $G\to\hat G$.

The representation theory text I am using defines the Fourier transform of a function $f:G\to \C$ as the function $\hat f:\hat G \to \C$ such that
$$
\hat f(\chi) = \langle f,\chi\rangle = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}f(g)\overline{\chi(g)}.
$$
So essentially $\hat f(\chi)$ is the scalar projection of $f$ onto $\chi$ using an inner product with respect to which the irreducible characters of $G$ form an orthonormal basis.

Meanwhile I see the QFT for a finite abelian group defined as the linear transformation $F_G$ such that
$$
F_G\ket g = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\sum_{x\in G}\chi_x(g)\ket x.
$$

Now, as far as I can tell, the relationship we get between the classical and quantum Fourier transforms is
\begin{align*}
\bra x F_G\ket g &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{|G|}}\chi_x(g)\\ 
&= \sqrt{|G|}\overline{\left(\frac{1}{|G|}\overline{\chi_x(g)}\right)} \\
&= \sqrt{|G|} \left(\overline{\hat\delta_g(\chi_x)}\right),
\end{align*}
where $\delta_g:G\to\C$ is 1 at $g$ and 0 elsewhere.

The fact that we get this conjugate seemed a little odd to me, and I was wondering whether this is an indication that there is some error or inconsistency in my reasoning (or incompatibility between my definitions), or if it is just “the way things work.” Alternatively, is there any more direct/elegant way of relating the QFT to the ordinary Fourier transform for a finite abelian group?

---

**Edit**: I thought it might also help to explain why I'm using the $\delta_g$ function, in case it is not clear. The classical Fourier transform is not applied to group elements but rather to maps $G\to\C$. It makes sense to think of a state like $\ket g$ (to which the QFT may be applied) as encoding the function on $G$ that is 1 at $g$ and 0 elsewhere, so to draw an analogue with the classical Fourier transform I considered applying the classical FT to that function, which is $\delta_g$. So the equation I got above is very nearly what I'd expect: ignoring the normalization factor, it *almost* says that the $\ket x$th entry of $F_G\ket g$ is equal to $\hat \delta_g(\chi_x)$, except there is a conjugate there. Meanwhile, I thought it would make more sense without the conjugate (in which case it would essentially be saying that the QFT and classical FT are the same thing).